# Having trouble with SQL injection

Tags: sql

I am a noob when it comes to understanding some of the attacks in SQL injection. I am currently seeing this attack in my log and was wondering if anyone can help me understand what it means

SQL Injection:

```
410'union/**/select/**/1/**/from/**/(select/**/count(*),concat(floor(rand(0)*2),0x3a,(select/**/concat(user,0x3a,password)/**/from/**/pwn_base_admin/**/limit/**/0,1),0x3a)a/**/from/**/information_schema.tables/**/group/**/by/**/a)b/**/where'1'='1.
```

Comment: Search for `parameterised queries` or `prepared statements`.  These ensure that an attacker can't *'break into'* your code by including SQL *(and specifically including the `'` character)* in free-form text parameters.  *(Your SQL statements will then look a bit like string builder patterns, with place holders for the parameters, rather than you directly substituting user entered values into your SQL.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont understand this completely, but the `select concat(user,0x3a,password) from pwn_base_admin` clearly tries to get a concatenated string of user names and passwords, divided by a ":"

The `concat(floor(rand(0)*2),0x3a,(` roughly does the same... the result would be something like `1:aUserName:UsersPassword`.

If you need further help please give some more details (RDBMS, the part before the "union"...)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Someone is actively trying to gain unauthorized access to your system - they're hacking in.

I don't know how critical this system is, but if it is of any importance, you should probably take the system offline until you sort out the database access part of the code. The first place to look for solutions is using bind parameters instead of string concatenation for your sql queries.

There are many resources available that describe how to use bind variables for whatever RDBMS you're using, but here is one article I found to get you started:

http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/bind-parameters